# Retrieving and Parsing Web Pages

Tags: c#, .net, web

I need help getting started on parsing web data using C# .NET.

I would like to create an app that automatically

1. goes to a site,
2. enters my login crecredentials using form authentication,
3. goes to certain pages,
4. retrieves and parses data, and then
5. saves the data into my DB.

Of course, this is assuming that the site does not expose any web services.

How do I get started? Is there any technical term for such a use case? I'm sure there are other apps that do the same thing.

Comment: Hi Erno, I'm just stuck at where to start :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/.  It allows retrieval of web pages and parsing of data.  You will will have to write the code to 'save data into my db'.

Comment: Thanks, I shall give this a try!